# Gmaps LatLng doesn't read my data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

Everything should be fine but its not. No console errors, nothing. Result of my object is displayed correctly in console and my marker is set up correctly if I manually type in coordinates.

However if I pass the data to LatLng with my object, zero results.

This in console returns "46.00,45.00":

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
console.log(data[0].coords);
```

and this sets up my marker for the Google maps:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.00,45.00);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
});
```

BUT! If I write it like this nothing happens:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng((data[0].coords));
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just passing one argument with `data[0].coords` as string, when you need to pass 2 arguments as numbers, as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng):

```
LatLng(lat:number, lng:number, noWrap?:boolean)
```

You'll need to split up the `coords` variable before:

```
var coordinates = data[0].coords.split(",");
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
```

Comment: Or... `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng.apply(null, data[0].coords.split(","));`

Comment: @FlorianMargaine that's not too readable. Also, it might break some optimisations.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh27 that was a joke. Use what the answer shows you. My code is barely readable.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `data.coords[0]`object completely to new `google.maps.LatLng`

You should split the lat and lon and pass it as below.

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].coords[0],data[0].coords[1]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
});
```